# The use of the expression "a Stag Party"

Tags: idioms, english-comparison, word-meaning

Could a " stag party" be used to define the Italian "Addio al celibato" ?

Comment: Sometimes _festa di addio al celibato_ is more appropriate than _addio al celibato_ alone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparing the English definiton of "[stag night](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o22Tajc1MVg)"

> "**A celebration** held for a man **shortly before his wedding**, attended by his **male friends only**."

to the Italian "[addio al celibato](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addio_al_celibato)"

> "**una festa** in onore di un uomo in procinto di sposarsi, tenuta **nei giorni immediatamente precedenti le nozze**, nella quale viene celebrato simbolicamente l'abbandono della condizione di celibe. Il rito sociale dell'addio al celibato è informato a uno spirito goliardico e vede la partecipazione dei più stretti amici del futuro sposo, **tutti di sesso maschile.**"

we can assume that they have the same meaning, as they include the same elements.

I'm sorry but I couldn't find official sources for the  definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that a Stag Night can be used to define the Italian "addio al celibato".
A fast source of this can be: [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/stag%20party.).